# unable to import file in a python package

Tags: python, package, python-import

I am trying to create a python package but I am having issues with imports.  This is the current situation:

```
[lpuggini@machinelearn-1 src]$ source ~/VirtualEnvs/time_series_algorithms_venv/bin/activate
(time_series_algorithms_venv) [lpuggini@machinelearn-1 src]$ tree                   
.
|-- TimeSeriesAlgorithms.egg-info
|   |-- PKG-INFO
|   |-- SOURCES.txt
|   |-- dependency_links.txt
|   `-- top_level.txt
|-- requirements.txt
|-- setup.py
`-- time_series_algorithms
    |-- __init__.py
    |-- __init__.pyc
    |-- examples
    |   |-- example_percentage_variation.py
    |   `-- example_percentage_variation.py~
    |-- percentage_varation.py
    `-- percentage_varation.pyc

3 directories, 12 files
(time_series_algorithms_venv) [lpuggini@machinelearn-1 src]$ python setup.py develop
/home/lpuggini/VirtualEnvs/time_series_algorithms_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/setuptools/dist.py:475: UserWarning: Normalizing '0.1dev' to '0.1.dev0'
  normalized_version,
running develop
running egg_info
writing TimeSeriesAlgorithms.egg-info/PKG-INFO
writing top-level names to TimeSeriesAlgorithms.egg-info/top_level.txt
writing dependency_links to TimeSeriesAlgorithms.egg-info/dependency_links.txt
reading manifest file 'TimeSeriesAlgorithms.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
writing manifest file 'TimeSeriesAlgorithms.egg-info/SOURCES.txt'
running build_ext
Creating /home/lpuggini/VirtualEnvs/time_series_algorithms_venv/lib/python2.7/site-packages/TimeSeriesAlgorithms.egg-link (link to .)
TimeSeriesAlgorithms 0.1.dev0 is already the active version in easy-install.pth

Installed /home/lpuggini/mlp/time_series_algorithms/trunk/src
Processing dependencies for TimeSeriesAlgorithms==0.1.dev0
Finished processing dependencies for TimeSeriesAlgorithms==0.1.dev0
```

and then when I try to run some code I get the following error:

```
(time_series_algorithms_venv) [lpuggini@machinelearn-1 src]$ python time_series_algorithms/examples/example_percentage_variation.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "time_series_algorithms/examples/example_percentage_variation.py", line 2, in <module>
    from time_series_algorithms.percentage_variation import PercentageVariationAD, PercentageVariationADConfig
ImportError: No module named percentage_variation
(time_series_algorithms_venv) [lpuggini@machinelearn-1 src]$
```

This is my `setup.py` file

```
(time_series_algorithms_venv) [lpuggini@machinelearn-1 src]$ cat setup.py 

from setuptools import setup, find_packages

setup(
    name='TimeSeriesAlgorithms',
    version='0.1dev',
    packages=find_packages(),
)
(time_series_algorithms_venv) [lpuggini@machinelearn-1 src]$
```

I do not know why this import is failing.  I am using python 2.7

**NOTE:**

I am able to import the module but not the python  file:

```
(time_series_algorithms_venv) [lpuggini@machinelearn-1 ~]$ python
Python 2.7.5 (default, Oct 30 2018, 23:45:53) 
[GCC 4.8.5 20150623 (Red Hat 4.8.5-36)] on linux2
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
>>> import time_series_algorithms
>>> from time_series_algorithms import percentage_variation
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
ImportError: cannot import name percentage_variation
>>> 
[
```

**ANSWER TO THE COMMENTS 1:** 
Also the option suggested in the comments fails

```
(time_series_algorithms_venv) [lpuggini@machinelearn-1 src]$ python time_series_algorithms/examples/example_percentage_variation.py
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "time_series_algorithms/examples/example_percentage_variation.py", line 2, in <module>
    from TimeSeriesAlgorithms.time_series_algorithms.percentage_variation import PercentageVariationAD, PercentageVariationADConfig
ImportError: No module named TimeSeriesAlgorithms.time_series_algorithms.percentage_variation
(time_series_algorithms_venv) [lpuggini@machinelearn-1 src]$
```

Comment: `from TimeSeriesAlgorithms.time_series_algorithms.percentage_variation import PercentageVariationAD, PercentageVariationADConfig` ?

Comment: it fails  I have edited the post. Also I think the original way should be the correct one.

Comment: @Donbeo You have a typo. The filename is called `time_series_algorithms/percentage_varation.py` and you're importing `time_series_algorithms.percentage_variation`.

Comment: I think you are right :-S

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is a simple typo in the name of the file that the OP has:

The file is called:

```
time_series_algorithms/percentage_varation.py
```

and the import statement is:

```
from time_series_algorithms.percentage_variation import PercentageVariationAD, PercentageVariationADConfig
```

so the file is `varation` and the import is `variation`.

This would have probably been observable in an IDE, or an strace of the python script itself would have revealed it being unable to open the `percentage_variation.py` file even though it looks to be there.

Comment: the import statement is `from time_series_algorithms.percentage_variation import PercentageVariationAD, PercentageVariationADConfig` fixing the typo it works :-)

Comment: oops, copy pasted from the update when creating the answer.